# Flask run bash commands from nginx instance

Tags: python, bash, nginx, flask

I'm building an API service so that my webserver (shared hosting) sends calls (`curl`) to an external Server (Ubuntu Server 16.04).

On the Ubuntu Server I have `Flask` installed with `nginx`, and works ok, and actually if I go to the IP and make a call this works.

`xx.xx.xx.xx/demo`

The problem is that some Flask functions have to execute bash commands and this is the problem.

The command does not get executed if run on the ngnix server but it does work if I manually run it on port 5000 via shell (`flask run --host=0.0.0.0`)

Therefore `xx.xx.xx.xx/demo` does not work and returns nothing while `xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/demo` works ok.

For example this:

```
@app.route('/dirsize/<path:fulldir>')
def jolly_dirsize(fulldir):
    cmd = "du -sh "+fulldir
    dati = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()
    return jsonify({'data':dati[0].split("\t")[0]})
```

Run on `XX.XX.XX.XX:5000/ls` returns

```
{"data":"API\nAPI.service\nAPI.sock\njolly.py\n"}
```

While `XX.XX.XX.XX/ls` returns;

```
{"data":""}
```

Even the `whoami` command returns empty when run in nginx.

**EDIT**:

After [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) suggestion I returned stderr/stout/status this way:

```
@app.route('/dirsize/<path:fulldir>')
def jolly_dirsize(fulldir):
    cmd = "du -sh "+fulldir
    dati = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    stdout, stderr = dati.communicate();
    status=dati.returncode; 
    return jsonify({'data': stdout, 'msg': stderr, 'status': status})
```

Now when running `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` I get this:

```
{
"data": "API\nAPI.service\nAPI.sock\njolly.py\n",
"msg": null,
"status": 0
}
```

While in nginx I get this:

```
{
"data": "",
"msg": null,
"status": 127
}
```

So 127 should mean `command not found`.

This is my `nginx` configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/wm/engine/API.sock;
    }
}
```

How do I go about this?

P.s: This command is just a test, I know is not safe and will not be executed this way in the future.

Comment: I'd suggest -- rather strongly -- not throwing away your stderr or exit status. stderr, in particular, is very likely to contain an explanation of your problem.

Comment: So `stdout, stderr = your_process.communicate(); status=your_process.returncode; return jsonify({'data': stdout, 'msg': stderr, 'status': status})` would give you much more to go on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you provide a snippet based on my code? I'm new to python.

Comment: Err, I *did* provide a snippet -- that's what's there in my second comment. Just store your `Popen` object in `your_process`, rather than calling `communicate()` in-line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks I get `statuscode` 0 in port 5000 and `statuscode`127 in nginx. I googled it and says `127 - command not found`. I update the question.

Comment: I'd suggest passing in an `env={'PATH':'/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin'}` argument, then.

Comment: Or make it `your_process = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/du', '-sh', fulldir], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, which doesn't use a shell to locate the command and so doesn't care about your PATH.

Comment: Great, where should I put it?

Comment: If you're adding an `env` argument, it should go in the `Popen` call. But the other version, with `shell=False`, is much safer (since a request with a directory named `$(rm -rf ~)` can't delete your files).

Comment: BTW, if you can find the PID of your Python process, you can check its environment: `tr '\0' '\n' </proc/PID/environ | grep PATH`; see if that's different when the PID is one of a manually-started process vs the started-by-nginx Python process.

Comment: (BTW, another advantageous thing about `shell=False` is that that way, instead of getting a numeric exit status from the shell you have to interpret, you get a direct Python exception if the program to run can't be found).

Comment: Dear Charles you are great, I'm new to python and I'd love to have a chat if possible. Do you mind?